# XCharter font in the beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts, xcharter

I would like to use the `XCharter` font package in the beamer environment, but only the writing is in this font, the mathematical environment I cannot change.

For a code,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{XCharter}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame.

Math: $f:X \to X$, $\{f^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output is
[image: 1]

But in a normal document, the mathematical environment should look like the image below.

[image: 2]

Comment: You may need `\documentclass{beamer}\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`.

Comment: @Clara I've tried to do that, but it's not correct. See the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJAeg.png 
The spacing is not correct, and it doesn't seem to be exactly the same....

Comment: What math font style do you want? You want serif in beamer? Or sans-serif in artile?

Comment: @Clara I want the mathematical environment in beamer to be the same as in the article, when I use XCharter.

Comment: I have put an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame.

Math: $f:X \to X$, $\{f^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that, if you’re making a Beamer presentation, you are not submitting a paper to someone who still requires you to use PDFTeX. So you can use modern fonts in LuaTeX or XeTeX.

Comment: @Davislor Better suggest just lualatex and not xelatex, the latter has some problems with beamer.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz And is also in maintenance mode, not being updated with new features.

Comment: @Davislor even better reason for lualatex :)

Answer (score 6):

If you compile with lualatex you can use the `xcharter-otf` package, which also loads the corresponding xcharter math font. This gives a more homogenous result than combining xcharter text with computer modern math.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{xcharter-otf}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame.

Math: $f:X \to X$, $\{f^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer pdflatex, you could use the `mathdesign` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame.

Math: $f:X \to X$, $\{f^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]